# Avoid right-floated DIV wrapping without adding any height in container

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to have a toolbar always aligned to the right within a `DIV` without adding any height. The problem I'm finding is making this work both when the box has 100% width and when the width is determined by content. The HTML looks something similar to this:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="title">
        float right
    </div>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
        <button>4</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I managed to make it work in Firefox, but Chrome wraps the toolbar when there is not enough space for it instead of increasing the width of the container.

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0 15px;
}
.title {
    display: inline-block;
}
.toolbar {
    background: #eee;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

I would like to find a single set of rules to achieve this regardless the width of the container, but I'm out of ideas unless I use some extra class to differentiate both cases. Also, I'm trying to avoid using `overflow` or `clearfix` because I don't want the toolbar to affect the height of the box.

In this fiddle I show all combinations I have tried: http://jsfiddle.net/omegak/c4y4t/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working in the end with a little hack.

I gave up on trying the title not to be `float: left`. Then, to prevent the box to have no height I added `overflow: hidden` to it. Finally, the hack consists on setting `margin-bottom: -999px` on the toolbar to prevent it from adding any extra height to the box.

Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/c4y4t/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, This worked for me.

```
.title {
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: This makes the first case in the fiddle to take no height (besides the padding) since both elements are floating. It could be solved by adding `overflow`, but then the `.toolbar` would determine the height of the container, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is the desired [output](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/c4y4t/7/)

Updated the below css and added clearfix class to the parent div

```
.title {
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It partially solves the problem, but the `clearfix` makes the toolbar to take up vertical space and I'm trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS and clear the floats on first Div.

```
.title {
   float:left;
}
```

[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mostwanted_cJ/JwgSY/1/)

Comment: Thanks. It partially solves the problem, but the `clear` makes the toolbar to take up vertical space and I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: That's because your toolbar height is greater than line height of title text. you need to increase line height or decrease toolbar height...